# How to show only specific category post by user role without plugin and restrict all other cats

Tags: functions, actions, user-roles, pre-get-posts, user-access

I am using basic post for adding posts. 5 categories exist ( cat_A, cat_B, cat_C, cat_D, cat_E). And I have 2 custom user_role for registered visitors that is 'viewer_a' and 'viewer_b'. I need to show only selected category post only for specific user roles.

So, users under 'viewer_a' can view only cat_A posts and under user_role 'viewer_B' can view cat_B posts only. Strictly restrict other posts.

How can I do that without plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using global loop for displaying the posts, then you can easily modify which posts are shown using `pre_get_posts` action.

```
function restrict_categories_for_user( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && get_current_user_id() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( in_array( 'viewer_a', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            // The user has the "viewer_a" role
            $query->set( 'category_name', 'cat_A' );  // <- use category slug here
        }
        if ( in_array( 'viewer_b', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            // The user has the "viewer_b" role
            $query->set( 'category_name', 'cat_B' );  // <- use category slug here
        }
    }
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'restrict_categories_for_user' );
```

I assume that you want to restrict which posts can be viewed by these users on front-end. If you want to restrict posts visible in back-end, then you'll have to change this condition `if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && get_current_user_id() ) {` accordingly...

Comment: user automatically redirecting to specific category posts, but the post_type "viewer_a" users can view the category post of post_type "viewers_b" posts if they copy the post url. there is no restriction. how can i restrict other category. user can view only the specific cat post. thanks for your answer. kindly update

Comment: front end restriction